# Adding into a total in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a column (C) tracking total hours for different projects for the year. New hours for the month are added in column B and I have manually been adding the new hours into the total. How to I create a formula that automatically updates the total hours in column C? I tried creating a formula but the formula gets messed up after a couple rows

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include a mock up of the data and expected output.

Comment: Do you want the C column to automatically add the new hours in column B? What formula does your C column use now? It seems that simply adding the data for the B column

Answer (score 0):

The formula

=SUM(C:C)

sums all values in column C. Is this what you are looking for?